# Wrapping NSTableView with Swift UI: How to use Bindings?

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui, combine

I am having a hard time managing the data that I want to pass to a
wrapped NSTableView View with SwiftUI. I tried using an `NSViewControllerRepresentable` but the problem is that my info is not getting updated as it should be.

I have a huge list (hundreds of thousands of items) of an `ObservableObject`:

```
class FileObject: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var id : String
    @Published var line : String
    
    init(id : String, line : String) {
        self.id = id
        self.line = line
    }
}
```

This is how I am calling my `NSViewControllerRepresentable` inside SwiftUI:

```
struct NSLinesList: View {
    @Binding var lines: [FileObject]
    
    var body: some View {
        LinesListTableRepresentable(objects: self.$lines)
    }
}
```

And this is the implementation of the NSViewController which contains a table view.

I have made the `Coordinator` to be the dataSource and the delegate of the tableView which is inside the NSViewController.

```
private let kColumnIDContentId = "number"
private let kColumnIdContent = "content"


struct LinesListTableRepresentable: NSViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias NSViewControllerType = LinesListViewController
    @Binding var objects : [FileObject]
    

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeNSViewController(context: Context) -> LinesListViewController {
        let storyboard = NSStoryboard.init(name: .init("Main"), bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "LinesListViewController") as! LinesListViewController
        return controller
    }

    func updateNSViewController(_ nsViewController: NSViewControllerType, context: Context) {
        nsViewController.tableView.dataSource = context.coordinator
        nsViewController.tableView.delegate = context.coordinator
    
        log.info("update the table view with \(self.objects.count) items")
        nsViewController.refresh()
    }
}

extension LinesListTableRepresentable {
    class Coordinator : NSObject, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {
        private let parent: LinesListTableRepresentable

        
        init(_ representable : LinesListTableRepresentable) {
            parent = representable
            super.init()
        }


        @objc public func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
            log.info("current object count inside table view: \(self.parent.objects.count)")
            return self.parent.objects.count
        }

        @objc func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

            guard let columnId = tableColumn?.identifier else { return nil }
            let currentLine = self.parent.objects[row]

            switch columnId {
            case .init(kColumnIDContentId):
                let tableCellView = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "lineNumbercell"), owner: self) as! LogNumberTableCell
                tableCellView.contentField.stringValue = "\(row)"
                tableCellView.wantsLayer = true
                return tableCellView
            case .init(kColumnIdContent):
                let tableCellView = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "lineContentCell"), owner: self) as! LogContentTableCell
                tableCellView.contentField.stringValue = currentLine.line
            default:
                break
            }

            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

I am putting some objects inside the `objects`, and although the `LinesListTableRepresentable` is getting the `objects` updated, the `Coordinator` always has 0 items!

My console output is this one:

```
2020-08-02T15:56:21+0300 info: update the table view with 2275 items
2020-08-02T15:56:21+0300 info: current object count inside table view: 0
```

So it seems that the `self.parent.objects.count` is always zero.

Can someone help with this?

Comment: Any reason why you are not using the SwiftUI native `List` view?

Comment: Yes, there is, It is a pain to setup for anything advanced, on MacOS the insets do not work like iOS, and I really need Column support.

Comment: Columns are a big thing in NSTableView. It did not take me long to understand that it will be far from simple to 're-invent' that look/behavior. (Not to mention tons of other things like drag/drop and others).

Comment: @csotiriou, have you been able to fix this issue? I’m running into the same situation and can’t figure out how to solve this for days.